# Как сделать, чтобы перед добавление новых данных добавлялись старые данные с другим атрибутом?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня реализован запрос, который сверяет и добавляет данные в таблицу, если были изменения в столбцах. Мне надо перед добавление новых данных, добавлялась старая информация с атрибутом (counts) -1. А потом уже сама информация с (counts) 1.

ТАблица и желаемый результат ---> https://dbfiddle.uk/IYEej8hM

запрос:

```
INSERT INTO result_chronol (source, object, redirect, serial_number, model) 
(SELECT id, date, source, object, redirect, serial_number, model 
 FROM chronol_2 
 EXCEPT SELECT id, date, source, object, redirect, serial_number, model 
 FROM chronol_1);
```

По умолчанию если данные записываются то они имеют изначально 1.

Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: "Сверяет" - по какому хоть критерию? *Возможно ли это сделать* Конечно. *и как ?* Дополнительный INSERT в CTE.

Comment: @Akina если в собаках были изменения в source или object serial_number остаётся всегда

Comment: @Akina извините, не могли бы помочь а то я немного не понимаю как сделать дополнительный insert?

Comment: *ТАблица и желаемый результат* Там ТРИ таблицы. Ну первая, допустим, исходное состояние. Последняя - желаемый результат. А вторая - это что? От первой она отличается только наличием ещё одного поля... Или вторая - это исходное состояние... тогда что есть первая? И где собственно те INSERT, после выполнения которых данные должны стать как в последней таблице? Да, а почему имена таблиц в fiddle и в тексте показанного запроса - не совпадают?

Comment: @Akina Забыл обновить, думал ссылка не изменится. Извините.

Comment: тут я балаюсь с запросом 
https://dbfiddle.uk/qc5A8YGV

Comment: Непонятно от слова совсем. Явно что-то там явно не по делу, надо всё лишнее убрать. Пожалуйста, оставьте: исходную таблицу с данными, INSERT-запрос вставки в неё (пофиг, что результат не тот, что нужен) и требуемый финальный результат. Запрос и требуемый результат можно оформить как комментарий, там же можно добавить и другие пояснения.

Comment: @Akina вот что получилось думаю это не правильно  https://dbfiddle.uk/q2Vt38_c 
 а вот пустая https://dbfiddle.uk/1ZM_SaHU